Cpanel disk warning 99%
I make websites for other companies and rent space at another web host. In Cpanel I get a disk warning: 99% under serverinformation (see image). My host provider tell me that nothing to think about, but I would like to know if others got some input about this. Is it nothing to be concerned about, or.. ?

Also I have to mention that under my own statistic, it says diskusage is 77%.

Are you able to ssh into the server, issue the command "df" and provide the result? Although I don't use it, my guess is that CPANEL is correct - it appears to be looking at 1 partition - and I wonder if you are looking at the combined results of all 3.   [ If any 1 partition is full, that can cause issues ]

I don't use CPANEL either but you should probably resize the disk

Thank you both for your comments. I haven't use ssh before, but I will go with the guess that there are more partition like davidgo is saying, and that one of the others most be pretty full..

It is likely accurate.  In cpanel go to disk usage in the "files" area.  You will see a breakdown of usage by directory and you can drill down into individual directories to inspect the data in more detail.


Thank you. It does seem like no one of my directories is that full, so I guess it must be another user of that shared hosting that is causing this.. Thanks for the feedback.

another user on shared hosting shouldn't affect your disk quota.

If you do have access to WHM & SSH I would goto
Server Configuration > Terminal
Install ncdu
## RHEL/Alama Linux/Rocky Linux/Centos
yum install ncdu

## Debian/Ubuntu
apt-get install ndcu

Then
cd /home && ncdu

It will take a while to calculate. Once it is done you will see the biggest folder at the top and then can use arrow keys to drill down and find the exact location where the large amount of disc space is being used

